# target command in wildstar

Tags: wildstar

Is there any command in Wildstar which is similiar to WoW's /target? 
It's a pain in the a** going back to questgivers when i have to abandon a quest because it's bugged.

About different commands I could only find [THIS](http://wildstar.mmorpg-life.com/guides/wildstar-list-controls-keyboard-commands/), but there is nothing which could be anything I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no slash command in the game for such action (at the moment, anyway).

After some research, I've been able to find an addon that could do what you want:

https://forums.wildstar-online.com/forums/index.php?/topic/9005-addon-slashtarget-v03/

I don't know if it works with the current API, but that's a beginning. The author mentioned other addons with graphical UI, which could do the work too.

Comment: awesome, even with hintarrows, this is exactly what i was looking for!